# Ads windows app development

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, sdk, ads

I'm currently programming a Windows store app. I included a ad with the example ad id. Now I wanted to take my own and registered an advertisement in the windows dev center. But it doesn't show up and an error occurred (method gets called). Can't I use my own ad id before it was successfully uploaded in the store? Or what did I do wrong?

So here my code XXX is of course secret:

```
InterstitialAd adname = new InterstitialAd(); //new Ad in Video Format

var APPID = "XXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXX"; //numbers and letters
var MyAdUnitId = "XXXXX"; //numbers
adname.AdReady += rdy;
adname.ErrorOccurred += Ezmoneyezlife_ErrorOccurred;
adname.Cancelled += Ezmoneyezlife_Cancelled;
adname.RequestAd(AdType.Video, APPID, MyAdUnitId);

adname.Show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/advertising-mobile-windows-phone-8-adcontrol-visual-designer(v=msads.20).aspx

> Live ads will not display in the emulator. In order to receive live
>   ads in the app you submit to the store you will need to replace the
>   test values of the AdControl with the live values from pubCenter. For
>   more information, see Getting Access to Microsoft pubCenter and
>   Receiving Ads.